# c# : Get country name from country code

Tags: c#, cultureinfo

I am trying using c# to get the country name from a country code

For example :

- `fr-fr` gets me France
- `it-it` gets me Italy

The problem with my code is that I am not getting the name but a information like this :

```
French (France)
```

This is my code :

```
var cultureInfo = new CultureInfo("fr-fr");
var result : cultureInfo.EnglishName
```

My result is `"French (France)"` instead of France.

I have managed to get what I want by use the parent property of the cultureInfo but I am not sure if it's a good method.

Comment: `fr-fr` and `it-it` are not country codes

Answer (score 8):

Because [`CultureInfo.EnglishName`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.englishname) *still* returns culture name.

You can create a [`RegionInfo`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.regioninfo) based on this culture and call *it's* [`EnglishName`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.regioninfo.englishname) property as well.

```
var cultureInfo = new CultureInfo("fr-fr");
var ri = new RegionInfo(cultureInfo.Name);
ri.EnglishName // France
```

or

```
var cultureInfo = new CultureInfo("it-it");
var ri = new RegionInfo(cultureInfo.Name);
ri.EnglishName // Italy
```

Comment: I have "**US**"... how to get country name from it..? It's not in "*us-usa*" format

Comment: `US` itself does _not_ refers any kind of culture or region on .net framework. You have to have a string like `en-US` for example. Then you might wanna use `TwoLetterISORegionName` which retuns `US` and `ThreeLetterISORegionName` which returns `USA` after you created the `RegionInfo` instance based on that cutlure. You have to do some string manipulation no matter what to get your string.

Answer (score 4):

You can get country name this way

```
RegionInfo cultureInfo = new RegionInfo("fr-fr");
string result = cultureInfo.EnglishName;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
var cultureInfoName = new RegionInfo(cultureInfo.Name);
string countryName = cultureInfoName.DisplayName;
```